# Null type safety warning when trying to check if an optional parameter is null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying out to build a REST API in Java and was testing out optional / non-required `@RequestParam`s, but I'm getting the following warning:

```
Null type safety: The expression of type 'String' needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@Nonnull String'Java(16778128)
```

In the code below:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v0.1/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<String> postUser(
        UserCreationDTO userData,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String ignoreRequest
    ) {
        try{
            if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(ignoreRequest)) { // <---------------------- HERE BE THE PROBLEM
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(ignoreRequest, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            return userService.createUser(userData);
        }catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        return BackendUtils.getResponseEntity(
            BackendConstants.SOMETHING_WRONG,
            HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        );

    }
```

A google search only throws back problems with people using raw Lists in ways that assumes the elements will be non-null. Here I am actually trying to check the "nullity" of a variable that could be null BY DESIGN. My reading of this is that `Strings.isNullOrEmpty` wants to receive an input string that is guaranteed to not be null? I'm probably not understanding this correctly, because that would completely defeat the purpose of the method...

Comment: Which `Strings` class is that?  The Java standard library does not have a class by that name.  Guava does, and that looks like a good candidate.  But since you're using Spring, why not keep it in-house, so to speak, by using [`org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.isEmpty()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ObjectUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.Object))?

Comment: Yes, I think it is probably guava (`import com.google.common.base.Strings`). Your suggestion is actually what I am doing now (actually `java.util.Objects.nonNull`, but same idea), I am just a bit wary there could some underlying problem I might be missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with annotation based nullity checking is that it falls apart into a mess of annoyance in either of these cases:

- You are forced to `@NonNull` **everywhere**. So, these systems fix the problem by either presuming everything is non-null *unless* annotated with `@Nullable`, possibly by not quite going that far (as that's thoroughly incompatible with default java - an assumption you shouldn't just be making) and relying on a `@NonNullByDefault` annotation to be applied to a class or even an entire package or module.
- nullity information is simply unknown for a bunch of methods used by the codebase. Which is, trivially, always true, because `java.*` is pretty much by definition 'used by the codebase', and **is not annotated**. Nullity annotation systems solve this problem using the concept of 'external annotations': Lists of 'patches' that indicate which parts of which method signatures in *external* code (i.e. dependencies; you just have the class files / the only source files you have are for reference, you don't compile these yourself) *should have had* a certain annotation.

With that as background, we can now get to the issue:

**Your nullity annotation linter is broken**.

Specifically, it is attempting to avoid the 'disaster zone' (usage of methods whose nullity is unknown); simply assuming 'hey its basic java we have no idea so for safety's sake, lets assume `@Nullable`' is *incredibly* annoying so it doesn't do that either.

Somewhere, these incentives went pearshaped, and has resulted in the linter tool guesstimating that, for this method:

```
package com.google.common.base;

public class Strings {
  ...

  public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(@NoNullityAnnotation String string) {
    ...
  }
}
```

... is to be treated as if that parameter was annotated as `@NonNull`. Which, trivially from the very name of the method, **is the incorrect guess**. Nevertheless, the nullity checker operates with this mistake made, and thus tells you that you're messing up: You can't pass a string to this `isNullOrEmpty` method without first ensuring it isn't null. And *that* is the warning you are getting.

This is quite nuts, because **guava does have null annotations!**.

So, your linter tool isn't even picking those up.

### A (timid) defense of your null annotation linter

The problem is, nullity via annotation is vastly more complicated than almost anybody realizes. For example, just like generics means that the notion of 'a list of numbers' actually has 4 flavours:

- `List<Number>`
- `List<? extends Number>`
- `List<? super Number>`
- `List /* raw / legacy mode */`

nullity in generics also comes in 4 flavours:

- List of definitely cannot be null strings. `.get(0)` *does not* require a null check. `.add(x)` cannot be called unless x is `@NonNull`.
- List of definitely can be null strings. `.get(0)` **does** require a null check; `.add(x)` can be called with anything, even un-null-checked stuff.
- List of I do not actually know. This is fine - as long as the code that accepts a `List<@WhoKnowsWhatNullity String>` adheres to **both** restrictions: It nullchecks the result of `.get(0)` **and** it never calls `.add(x)` where `x` isn't known to be non-null, then it *does not matter*
- Legacy/raw mode: The code does what it does, it isn't safe, and the compiler is not going to stop it from happening; analogous to raw mode in generics.

And yet pretty much no null annotation framework has this; few know about it, and some that do (such as JSpecify, whose authors know about this stuff) are last time I checked on the fence whether this complication is worth it. CheckerFramework, for what its worth, does do it (`@PolyNull` is their solution to this). And that's just one of a bunch of complications.

So, as a result, there are literally 15 nullity annotation systems and most don't *quite* match up in semantic meaning, which in turn means nullity checkers can't just code in knowledge of all the common nullity frameworks and run with it.

Then again, guava is one of the most popular libraries, it does have nullity annotations, and this nullity linter checker decided to just blindly (and wrongly) guess 'surely, @NonNull is what was intended here'), which is a really really bad guess. So, you mostly have crappy tools here and you might want to file some feature requests they do a much, much better job at their guesswork. Because this wrong guess is hard to excuse.

### Fixing it

No doubt your linting system has an external annotation system. Check if someone made definitions for guava, and add them to the external annotations store. If not, make it yourself. The problem will then go away. If you can't find em for guava, you're either going to have to deal with a cavalcade of false warnings, or, you have to ditch guava, or, you have to ditch your nullity linter. For this exact case, 'ditch guava' is the easy answer because `isNullOrEmpty` exists everywhere. But, probably you use guava in lots more places in your codebase, and surely your linter tool is misguessing guava's nullity in more places than just `isNullOrEmpty`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! I definitively was not able to follow a 100% since I'm relatively new to java, but this sounds a bit like the problem they have in Python with type hinting adoption and checkers like mypy. In any case, for now I'll just drop guava and just use `java.util.Objects.nonNull` (and, from other sources I checked, also try to use optional as much as possible). But I'll refer back to this whenever I stump into other "potentially null" issues!

Comment: Optional is.. not where the valhalla lies, @Nordico. It's incompatible with many libraries and misses most of these nuances. I recommend against its use; it is a great idea as return type of a stream operation (which is where java itself uses it a lot), it's debatably fine as return type of any method, and it should not show up anywhere else. No field should be typed `Optional`, no parameter should be typed `Optional`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that you'll need to change your Eclipse settings to treat `javax.annotation.CheckForNull` (the annotation currently used for parameters and return types in Guava) as a `Nullable` annotation.

It looks like you would set that [under Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings in the "Use default annotations for null specifications" section](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/compiler/ref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm#null_analysis).